# Return time of random walk on a tree

Tags: pr.probability

Consider a simple random walk on a fixed (generic) finite tree, starting at a given vertex. Is there a nice upper bound on the second moment of the return time?

Comment: Formula 2.22 of Aldous-Fill gives you a nice formula for the variance in terms of the expected hitting time starting from the stationary distribution.

Comment: Thank you, Nicolas!